# SwiftUI Grid is overflowing the view when zoomed

Tags: swiftui

I have an app that displays a calendar, like so:

[image: Calendar]

It uses a Grid with GridRows.

Unfortunately, many users have the Display Zoom option set to Larger Text. In this case the Grid overflows the view like this:

[image: Calendar overflowing]

Is there something I could do to prevent this overflowing?

Here's the code (I know, I should use ForEach to avoid duplication...)

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    let dayWidth = cellWidth(width: geometry.size.width)
    
    Grid(alignment: .top, horizontalSpacing: 1, verticalSpacing: 1) {
        GridRow {
            Text("Mo")
            Text("Tu")
            Text("We")
            Text("Th")
            Text("Fr")
            Text("Sa")
            Text("Su")
        }
        .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: dataManager.fontSize * 16/19))
        .bold()
        Divider()
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[0], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[0])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[1], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[1])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[2], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[2])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[3], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[3])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[4], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[4])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[5], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[5])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[6], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[6])
                }
        }
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[7], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[7])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[8], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[8])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[9], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[9])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[10], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[10])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[11], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[11])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[12], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[12])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[13], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[13])
                }
        }
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[14], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[14])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[15], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[15])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[16], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[16])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[17], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[17])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[18], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[18])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[19], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[19])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[20], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[20])
                }
        }
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[21], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[21])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[22], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[22])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[23], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[23])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[24], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[24])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[25], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[25])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[26], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[26])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[27], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[27])
                }
        }
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[28], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[28])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[29], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[29])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[30], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[30])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[31], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[31])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[32], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[32])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[33], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[33])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[34], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[34])
                }
        }
        GridRow {
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[35], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[35])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[36], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[36])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[37], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[37])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[38], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[38])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[39], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[39])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[40], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[40])
                }
            CalendarDayView(dataManager.month.days[41], width: dayWidth, fontSize: dataManager.fontSize)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showDayInDayView(day: dataManager.month.days[41])
                }
        }
    }
    .padding(5)
}
```

Comment: *How* do you want to stop it from overflowing? Do you want to make each cell smaller? Have less padding around the numbers? Or just disable dynamic type all together?

Comment: Well, I wrote code to fit seven cells in a row, using GeometryReader. And you see that it works fine, without zoom. But with zoom everything goes awry.

Comment: Please include the code for CalendarDayView too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your calendar is designed to fit 7 days across the full width of the screen. Of course, depending on the screen size, this means the days may occupy very different widths. The same probably goes for the heights too.

One approach would be to set `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` on the cells for each date. This way, the days will share the available space. Then use a large font and allow it to be scaled to fit by using a combination of `.lineLimit`, `allowsTightening` and `minimumScaleFactor` modifiers. This will also help to counteract larger text sizes.

Something like this:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0...3, id: \.self) { week in
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(1...7, id: \.self) { day in
                Text("\((week * 7) + day)")
                    .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: 50))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .allowsTightening(true)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                    .border(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestions but they didn't have any effect. I'll post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Silly me. As @Benzy Neez guessed correctly, the problem was not in the layout I've shown but in the CalendarDayView component. In it, I am using images that weren't resized properly and were causing the overflow. As soon as I started taking into account the actual width of the calendar cell and resizing the images appropriately, I was able to fix the problem.